# How can I convert the input value into Unicode and print it out?

Tags: java

I have to input Hello through Scanner and print it on the console with decimal numbers corresponding to each alphabet. The output values should be in a single line. I have to use 'char'. Help me!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String var = "scan";
        
        char a = var.charAt(0);
        char b = var.charAt(1);
        char c = var.charAt(2);
        char d = var.charAt(3);
        char e = var.charAt(4);
        
        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(c);
        System.out.print(d);
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have to use 'char'` can you elaborate? Does this mean you can't use int?

Comment: @ManavChhibber no! You can use int of course! But I'm doing my homework and my professor says I have to use char....

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Always use code point integers, never `char`.

For a single line of output to console:

```
 System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString( "Hello".codePoints().toArray() )
 );
```

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 128075]
```

For separate lines:

```java
for( int codePoint : "Hello".codePoints().toArray() )
{
    System.out.println( 
        "codePoint = " + codePoint + " = " 
        + Character.toString( codePoint ) 
    ) ;
}
```

```
codePoint = 72 = H
codePoint = 101 = e
codePoint = 108 = l
codePoint = 108 = l
codePoint = 111 = o
codePoint = 128075 =
```

## Code point integers, not `char`

Actually, the `char` type is obsolete, unable to represent even half of the 143,859 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Instead, use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. This number is what you after anyways in your school assignment.

The `String` class offers a method [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) to get a stream of the code point integers.

```
IntStream codePointStream = "Hello".codePoints() ;
```

You can turn that stream into a simple array of `int` primitive values.

```
int[] codePoints = codePointStream.toArray() ;
```

Loop the elements of that array. Print each number to the console. And print the character assigned to that code point number by calling [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

```java
for( int codePoint : codePoints )
{
    System.out.println( "codePoint = " + codePoint + " = " + Character.toString( codePoint ) ) ; 
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne](https://ideone.com/OH0UqM).

```
codePoint = 72 = H
codePoint = 101 = e
codePoint = 108 = l
codePoint = 108 = l
codePoint = 111 = o
```

Now, make it more interesting by including a character that would fail if we were using the obsolete `char` type, character WAVING HAND SIGN at decimal code point 128,075:  `Hello`

```
codePoint = 72 = H
codePoint = 101 = e
codePoint = 108 = l
codePoint = 108 = l
codePoint = 111 = o
codePoint = 128075 =
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Scanner(System.in).next().chars().forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

input:

```
Hello
```

output:

```
72101108108111
```